# variable value change after strcpy function in C

Tags: c

i noticed that variable value have been changed after strcpy function,i don't know how and why this is happening.
this is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main()
{
    int b = true;
    char ch[3];
    strcpy(ch,"int");
    printf("b value is:%d\n",b);

    return 0;
}
```

I even use a temporary integer variable. it's very strange , in this case, the b value is correct after strcpy but the temp is changed to 0, note that it's just happened when assigning 1 value to b and temp variables.
this is the second code

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main()
{
    int b = true;
    int tmp=b;
    char ch[3];
    strcpy(ch,"int");
    printf("b value is:%d\n",b);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Please only tag the language you are using (C or C++, but not both).

Comment: Copying your example into Compiler Explorer produces a warning: 'void* __builtin_memcpy(void*, const void*, long unsigned int)' writing 4 bytes into a region of size 3 overflows the destination [-Wstringop-overflow=]

Comment: *i don't know how and why this is happening* -- Buffer overrun is the reason -- one of the most exploited parts of a computer program.  You see how it changed your data -- that is exactly what a hacker would do.  Thus use `std::string`, where these things are not present (or very minimal presence).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly, you need to use number (0,1) in your boolean variables. If you want to use boolean in C as you use them in c++, you have to include stdbool.h library.

Concerning strcpy(dest, src) function, it copies the src string to dest and return à pointer to the copied string.

In reality the size of "int" is not 3 but 4 bytes. String always ends with '\0' character.

In other words :

If you don't understand, try to analyze this code :

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

   int main()
    {
        int b = 1;
        char ch[4];
        strcpy(ch,"int");
        printf("b value is:%d\n",b);

        return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 6):

```
strcpy(ch,"int");
```

is equivalent to

```
ch[0] = 'i';
ch[1] = 'n';
ch[2] = 't';
ch[3] = 0;
```

Seeing as `ch` only has three elements (`ch[0]..ch[2]`), this invokes undefined behaviour.

Comment: At first I thought you were wrong, but now I realize. Thankful

Answer (score 0):

I used [online compiler](https://www.onlinegdb.com/online_c_compiler#) and selected "C++" and the error is not happening.
but when I selected C++17 I  got this warning ***"
input
main.cpp:9:12: warning: ‘void* __builtin_memcpy(void*, const void*, long unsigned int)’ writing 4 bytes into a region of size 3 ov
w=] "***

as @PaulMcKenzie mentioned this is buffer overflow case.

Comment: This isn't necessarily a buffer overflow case.. Its best be termed as Undefined Behavior.

Comment: @WedaPashi, It is a buffer overflow, and the result of a buffer overflow is Undefined Behaviour.